# Promise.all produced "throttle queue is over max capacity"

Tags: javascript, node.js

When running this code, I get "trottle queue is over max capacity" error and I dont know how to get this to work.

The function that gets called for the service itself is an async function call to a 3rd party API. I could not find any implementation that works for my example and hope to find someone to explain me what is happening here.

Thank you

```js
async analyze() {
    const markets = Object.values(this.service.getMarkets()).filter(
      (m) => this.markets.includes(m.quoteId) && m.active
    );
    const tasks = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < markets.length; i++) {
      //market iteration
      const symbol = markets[i].symbol;

      for (let j = 0; j < this.timeframes.length; j++) {
        //timeframe iteration
        const timeframe = this.timeframes[j];
        tasks.push(this.service.getOHLCV(symbol, timeframe));
      }
    }

    console.log("Tasks to be executed", tasks.length);

    const startTime = Date.now();
    const ohlcvDatasets = await Promise.all(tasks);
    const endTime = Date.now() - startTime;

    console.log(`executed ${tasks.length} tasks in ${endTime} ms`);
    
    this.analyzeRSI(ohlcvDatasets);
  }
```

this.service.getOHLCV() returns a Promise. The function in the service class makes use of a 3rd party library which calls an external API.

Like so.

getOHLCV(){
return 3rdPartyAPICall
}

Comment: What does `this.service.getMarkets()` and `this.service.getOHLCV(symbol, timeframe)`  and `this.analyzeRSI ` returns?

Please add more code to make it easier to see what went wrong. 

Also please add the error stack trace / message that you see in the logs.

Comment: How many is `tasks.length`? It probably exceeds the API's capacity. You are launching all these tasks concurrently. I believe the API is trying to throttle the calls, but there are just too many of them

Comment: I edited the original post below. Task lengths on the one that throws an error is roughly above 1000. What would be the efficient way to avoid this capacity error? Should I further split the tasks array into several parts with a delay or is there a better way?